# Find a real number $k$ such that this limit has a positive value.

Tags: limits

Find a real number $k$ such that the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1^4+2^4+3^4+4^4+\ldots+n^4}{n^k}$$
has a positive value.

My apologies.
I'm a complete zero in this. I didn't try anything because I have no idea what should I do, please explain all the steps for solving the problem.

Comment: Well look up Stolz-Cesaro theorem,or if you're russian https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%A8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B0

Comment: The question is incomplete. What property should this $k$ have? Should the limit exist? Or be $0$? Or what?

Comment: Can't solve the problem, since you haven't stated a problem. What exactly problem is it that you are trying to solve?

Comment: From the consequences of the theorem of Stolz, k probably equal to 4, but i guess, my stupid brain, do something wrong

Comment: $k=\pi$ is a good answer to the question in the title.  $k=0$ is another good answer.   Since these are not answers to the question you want to ask, please try to improve the title.

Comment: ok, i remeber it for future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$S(n):=1^4+2^4+3^4+4^4+\ldots+n^4.$$
The first order backward difference verifies
$$\nabla S(n):=S(n)-S(n-1)=n^4,$$
so that $S(n)$ must be a polynomial of the fifth degree in $n$, and the ratio $$\frac{S(n)}{n^5}$$ has a finite limit.

---

More precisely, if the leading term of $S(n)$ is $an^5$, the leading term of $\nabla S(n)$ is that of $\nabla an^5$, i.e. $5an^4$, and the limit is $a=\frac15$.

Comment: Thx, its really helpfull, this kind of proof, i`ll use in exam.

Comment: Yep, it takes no computation at all :) Upvote welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1^4+2^4+\cdots+n^4}{n^5}=\int_{0}^{1}x^4dx=\dfrac{1}{5}$$

Comment: not $\dfrac{6}{30}=\dfrac{1}{5}?$

Comment: I forgot my brain at work, I assume ^^ Sorry for the disturbance.

Comment: How you did it? I please you explain.

Comment: Do you known Rimann Integral?

Comment: I tried to look into it, but realizing that I do not understand it, i decided to strengthen my position in the lighter areas

Comment: @МузаффарШакаров Note that
$$\frac{1^4 + \ldots + n^4}{n^5} = \frac1n ((1/n)^4 + (2/n)^4 + \ldots + (n/n)^4) = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n (k/n)^4$$
This is a right Riemann sum for the integral
$$\int_0^1 x^4\ \mathrm dx$$

Answer (score 0):

The Stolz Cesaro theorem yields  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^4}{(n+1)^k-n^k}$$

The degree of the numerator is $4$ while the degree of the denominator is $k-1$. So if $k \le 4$, the limit is $\infty$. 
If $k \ge 6$, the limit is $0$.

If $k = 5$, you only need to compute the coefficient of $n^4$ in the denominator, and the binomial theorem easily yields $\binom 51 = 5$. So the limit if $k=5$ is $\frac 15$

Comment: Oh, its easy to understand thx for answer

Answer (score 0):

You can prove $1^4+2^4+3^4+\cdots+n^4=\frac{1}{5}n^5+\frac{1}{2}n^4+\frac{1}{3}n^3-\frac{1}{30}n$ using simple induction.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1^4+2^4+3^4+\ldots+n^4}{n^k}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{5}n^5+\frac{1}{2}n^4+\frac{1}{3}n^3-\frac{1}{30}n}{n^k}$$

If $k<5$, the limit is $\infty$, if $k>5$, the limit is $0$.

For $k=5$, the limit is $1/5$.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{1}{5}n^5+\frac{1}{2}n^4+\frac{1}{3}n^3-\frac{1}{30}n}{n^5}$$

$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{3n^2}-\frac{1}{30n^4}\right)$$